# CardView animation: raise and expand on click?

Tags: android, animation, expand, raise

I'm currently in the process of creating my first android app, and was wondering what the method would be to set a cardview to raise up and then expand into a larger rectangle, revealing a new fragment?

edit: (the new fragment would fill up the center third of the screen, no matter where the original card was located)

Answer (score 3):

> **Authentic Motion**
>
> Tangible surfaces don’t just appear out of nowhere like a jump-cut in
>   a movie; they move into place helping to focus attention, establish
>   spatial relationships and maintain continuity. Materials respond to
>   touch to confirm your interaction and all changes radiate outward from
>   your touch point. All motion is meaningful and intimate, aiding the
>   user’s comprehension.
>
> **Activity + Fragment Transitions**
>
> By declaring ‘shared elements’ that are common across two screens you
>   can create a smooth transition between the two states.
>
> ```
> album_grid.xml
> …
>     <ImageView
>         …
>         android:transitionName="@string/transition_album_cover" />
> album_details.xml
> …
>     <ImageView
>         …
>         android:transitionName="@string/transition_album_cover" />
>
> AlbumActivity.java
> Intent intent = new Intent();
> String transitionName = getString(R.string.transition_album_cover);
> …
> ActivityOptionsCompat options =
> ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity,
>     albumCoverImageView,   // The view which starts the transition
>     transitionName    // The transitionName of the view we’re transitioning to
>     );
> ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, intent, options.toBundle());
> ```
>
> Here we define the same transitionName in two screens. When starting
>   the new Activity and this transition is animated automatically. In
>   addition to shared elements, you can now also choreograph entering and
>   exiting elements.

Source: [Implementing Material Design](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/implementing-material-design-in-your.html)

Comment: can we do it with card views?

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. create a xml file in *res-> anim -> sale_up.xml*
2. copy this animation file and paste to your sale_up.xml file. Code bellow -

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <scale
>         android:fromXScale="1.0"
>         android:fromYScale="1.0"
>         android:toXScale="1.2"
>         android:toYScale="1.2"
>         android:duration="500"
>         android:pivotX="50%"
>         android:pivotY="50%" />
> </set>
> ```

3. Now go to your activity or fragment and attatch the animation to your cardview like this -

> ```
> // initialize the animation
> val animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(requireActivity(), R.anim.scale_up)
> // attatch the animation while performing onClick on the desire cardview
> binding.cardview.setOnClickListener {
>     it.startAnimation(animation)
> }
> ```